# Subversion restrict user access

Tags: svn, authorization

Can any one help me with this confusion…
I have setup SVN server correctly with trunk, branch, tags and everything is working correctly.
My problem is with authorization & access.

I have created SVN users, through command line, using the following command

```
htpasswd -cm /etc/svn-auth-users harry
```

and my subversion.conf file has the following -

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repositories"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

It is evident, that user and password (encrypted) stored in /etc/svn-auth-users

Question 1. Then what is the use of the files “authz” and “passwd” inside my repo/conf/
Question 2.  In my situation, as stated above (i.e., using the file /etc/svn-auth-users), how do I restrict users to a particular branch.

Note: Everywhere, I see user access is restricted using the “authz” file.

```
.
.
.
[my_repo:/branches/calc]
harry = rw
bobby = r
.
.
.
```

I even tried that, but has no effect. Any user, created using the command line above, can access trunk.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authz` and `passwd` files in the repository directory are used if you access the repository via SVN's own protocol, e.g.: `svn://server/repo`

If you're using the apache module you'll access the repository via HTTP and apache will handle the authentication. You can also use the `authz` file (with identical syntax) for that, but you need to tell apache where it is in your configuration file:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn-authz

    Require valid-user
</Location>
```