# svn restrict specific folder repository

Tags: ubuntu, svn

Can any one help me with this confusion… I have setup SVN server correctly. My problem is with authorization & access.

I have created SVN users, through command line, using the following command

htpasswd -cm /etc/svn-auth-users harry
and my dav_svn.conf file has the following -

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repositories"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

It is evident, that user and password (encrypted) stored in /etc/svn-auth-users

Question 1. Then what is the use of the files “authz” and “passwd” inside my repo/conf/ Question 2. In my situation, as stated above (i.e., using the file /etc/svn-auth-users), how do I restrict users to a particular branch.

Note: Everywhere, I see user access is restricted using the “authz” file.

```
.
.
.
[my_repo:/branches/calc]
harry = rw
bobby = r
.
.
.
```

I even tried that, but has no effect. Any user, created using the command line above, can access trunk. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I followed the same method as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566589/subversion-restrict-user-access . But when i follow the above method and access the repository  I am getting svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL , svn: E175013: Access to repo folder forbidden. can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` in your apache snapshot that you have attached.
You need to put the location of `authz` file in the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` apache configuration.

You have that one line missing

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repositories"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/path/authz
Require valid-user
</Location>
```